# ¿Como puedo hacer que desde una LAN Interna pueda hacer ping por ejemplo a cocacola.es?

Tags: bash, iptables, firewall

Estoy haciendo un script que haya diferentes reglas con iptables y la LAN interna tiene como interfaz enp0s8 y la interfaz que va a internet es la enp0s3 y lo que no entiendo es como puedo hacer que desde la red 172.16.30.0/24 que es la que esta en enp0s8 pueda hacer ping hacia cualquier web de internet :

Os dejo el codigo del script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables -X

sudo iptables -Z

sudo iptables -t nat -F

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP

sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.10:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.10:443
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.11:22

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.30.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 22 -d 172.16.30.11 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s3 -i enp0s8 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT


sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -d 172.16.30.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.30.1 -p icmp -j DROP

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s3 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s3 -p icmp -j ACCEPT


sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s8 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s8 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: No necesitas que salga a internet por la interfaz local. Para eso se usa la *tabla de enrutamiento* con reglas bien definidas, para que el equipo pueda decidir por qué interfaz salir. Ej. 0.0.0.0 saldría por la interfaz enp0s3, mientras que 172.16.0.0/24 saldría por enp0s8.

Answer (score 0):

> Entendiendo el escenario como que el servidor intermedio si tiene ping a cocacola.es, y responde. Y que los ordenadores en LAN tengan como ruta por defecto ese servidor donde se lanza esa configuración de iptables.

Tu configuración de Firewall es una obra de arte y es correcta. Después de revisar regla por regla, solo puede ser que no tengas el `ipv4_forwarding` del `kernel` activado.

Compruebalo con:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Habilitalo con:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Para hacer este cambio persistente, descomenta la siguiente linea `/etc/sysctl.conf` :

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

En caso de que ni así funcione, te recomiendo que hagas un `FLUSH` de todo el FIREWALL, y que solo dejes la regla que enmascare el trafico LAN a Internet.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.30.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
```

> Por qué?  Porque el router no conoce la `LAN` ( a nose que le hayas indicado donde se encuentra 172.16.30.0/24 con ruta estática), así que debe ver los paquetes de `LAN` como si fuera el `HOST` que si conoce -----> de eso trata el `MASQUERADE`

Y una a una vete insertando reglas. Los default DROPS para las ultimas.

#### apuntes del trabajo de análisis

Resumen de las comprovaciones hechas, para entender que esta haciendo cada regla.

Orden de la cadena transversal

Asumiendo que el servidor conoce como enrutar al paquete y que las reglas de firewall lo perimten, este es el orden de actuación:

> Paquetes de entrada destinados al sistema: `PREROUTING` -> `INPUT`

> Paquetes de entrada destinado a otro hosts: `PREROUTING` -> `FORWARD` -> `POSTROUTING`

> Paquetes generados localmente: `OUTPUT` -> `POSTROUTING`

RESUMEN:

```
#enp0s8  LAN 172.16.30.0/24
#enp0s3  INTERNET

#!/bin/bash


# REGLAS GENERALES
iptables -F  # FLush, limpiar
iptables -X  # Limpia chain vacias
iptables -Z  # Contadores a 0
iptables -t nat -F # Flush nat table
iptables -P INPUT DROP  # by default drop
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP  # by default drop
iptables -P FORWARD DROP   # by default drop


# NATs especificos
## DESTINATION NATS, vienen de internet y van a un host LAN CONCRETO
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.10:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.10:443
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.30.11:22

# IMPORTANTISIMA, ENMASCARAR TRAFICO SALIDA A INTENRET QUE VIENE DE LAN
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.30.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

# RE-ENVIOS
## DE INTERNET A LAN,
iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 22 -d 172.16.30.11 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -d 172.16.30.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o enp0s8 -i enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

## DE LAN A INTERNET
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3  -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT



# INPUT Y OUTPUT HACEN REFERENCIA AL MISMO SERVIDOR
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.30.1 -p icmp -j DROP

# HACIA INTERNET
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s3 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# VIENE DE INTERNET
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s3 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s8 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s8 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Si donde quiero hacer ping por ejemplo alguna pagina web tiene que ser desde la red 172.16.30.0